# Nginx 502 Error only with full page cache enabled or trying to go to the admin

Tags: magento2, nginx, server-setup, redis, php-fpm

Even after disabling my custom module I'm getting this error.  When I stopped working on it the day before this wasn't the case.  It was working fine and I've been using this same server to develop for about 2 months with no issue like this.  I verified I didn't change any major config files.  I even tried upgrading magento itself and the exact same behavior continues everything works fine until you try to log into the admin or enable full page cache.

Spent at least 3 hours on this already anyone have any ideas?  I get segmentation fault in messages for php-fpm.  But I verified all the settings are correct and can even telnet to the php-fpm server.  I'm not sure cause is but I verified the server runs fine even opened a phpinfo(); test page just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by taking the segfaults as a cue.  I used this as a guide: https://ma.ttias.be/generate-php-core-dumps-segfaults-php-fpm/

After installing gdb and yum-utils so I could run the debug-info gdb prompted me to it all worked and I found it was calling the redis module just before it crashed.  I disabled it and set sessions to be saved to files, as well as the php.ini this made the full page caching work but admin logins still didn't work I had to fix another error for it, it was setting my session to expire before I logged in.  I found the solution to that here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5309

first step:
in your mysql databse find path "admin/security/session_lifetime" in table core_config_data.  if the row doesn't exist create it.  Set the value to 86400

second step:
clean cache (remove var/cache)

After this everything was working great.